# CSS selector to trigger Google Tag Manager

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I am trying to use a CSS-selector trough Google Tag Manager on my website but the CMS system used uses a different tag standards(?).

I am trying to achieve to get the "Value" in this tag:

```
<ul k="redmeta">
   <i k="PageType" value="Andre produkter"></i>
   <i k="ProduktKategori" value="Tilhenger"></i>
   <i k="ProduktNavn" value="Basic 750"></i>
</ul>
```

What I tried is:

```
ul[k="redmeta"] i    --> nothing
ul.k --> nothing
ul.redmeta --> nothing
```

Hope someone can help me get the values inside these tags "PageType", "ProduktKategori", and "ProduktNavn".

**What i want is:**

```
ul[k="redmeta] li[k="PageType" Value ] ---> "Andre Produkter"
```

New to CSS-selector, I can get easy metadata but this one is a little tricky since there is no "Class" attribute, but uses "K", dont know if this makes any difference?

Thanks!

Asim

Comment: I don't think you can get the value of an element using css

Comment: You can have CSS use value as dynamic content, **BUT** 1. `<i>` do not have `value` as a valid attribute. 2. The form controls (ex. `<input>`)  can have `value` **BUT** cannot have dynamic content because it's a void element (i.e. no end tag).

Comment: Is `K` attaribute part of the Google Tag Manager API?

Comment: You might have to use JavaScript for that as there is no way to *get the value form a tag* in CSS. There is [css-content property](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/) tho.

Comment: @zer00ne no, this is a CMS-system that uses therse attributes. Dont know why, but maby because this is a norwegian based CMS and instead of "Class" we say "Klasse" with a "K".

Comment: Well i am able to get value from example meta tags with css-selector in GTM why cant i get the attribute value from a standard tag?

Comment: I believe it's because the attributes are invalid on these elements thus the behavior  (if any) is not what's expected. Use `data-*` attributes, they are universal. Of course that would involve JavaScript...

Comment: @zer00ne so what youre saying is that the "K=" is the problem because it is not a valid attribute? and even if it was "class" there should not be expected that i could get the value attribute with css-selector?

Comment: Could you give a complete sample code? Maybe you are using something like jquery selector?

Comment: Don't treat `k` as a class, treat it as an attribute `[k='whatever']`

Comment: @Asim Please consider tagging this question with something like `google-tag-manager`. We're getting confused because I don't think you really want to do CSS after all. You just want to use a [CSS selector to trigger Google Tag Manager](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/matches-css-selector-operator-in-gtm-triggers/). Otherwise, Javascript could get that attribute.

Comment: @Cons7an7ine I did then I deleted it because it's just like Mr. Brosch's and it appears Mr. Asim has an issue with it. Using CSS for what I think is the goal is impossible, JavaScript does the impossible on a daily basis.

Comment: i would use JavaScript absoloutly, but i am using Google Tag Manager and trying to only use variables to get the values, not custom HTML to add javascript

Comment: Most unfortunate, Google's twist on JavaScript is class oriented as if they are trying to run it like Java. It's confusing because the syntax is so specialized, good luck, sir.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you need to do in Google Tag Manager. Do you want to report on how many times that visitors clicked on "Andre Produkter"? Do you want a list of all the values they clicked on?

Comment: Does your CMS produce valid HTML? The HTML example you gave wouldn't be visible in a browser. I had to modify it to show up on https://jsfiddle.net/h15qxvz4/2/

Comment: This is supposed to be a "metadata" not something that should be visible. No i am trying to add this data as "meta" so i can extract the values from what productpage is beeing viewed with contentEngagement not "clicked to Andre produkter". The url is structured a way that i cant use URL as a trigger also. Ive asked the CMS-support if they can add a dataLayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a Trigger in Google Tag Manager to fire under a variety of conditions, but your condition isn't one of their standard options. Some of the default options will let the trigger fire when a variable matches or doesn't match a CSS selector, or matches or doesn't match RegEx. Simo Ahava explains some of the options in his blog post [“Matches CSS Selector” Operator In GTM Triggers](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/matches-css-selector-operator-in-gtm-triggers/). Maybe you could use the "[DOM Element](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#8)" Variable Type with a Selection Method of CSS Selector and the value as `i[k='ProduktKategori']` and the Attribute Name as `value`.

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/matches-css-selector-operator-in-gtm-triggers/

Comment: This is exactly what i needed @Michael, works like charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I,m little bit confuse what you trying to achieve. However try the following code if work for you:

```
ul[k='redmeta'] li[k='PageType'] {
  write css your code here..
}


<ul k="redmeta">
   <li k="PageType" value="Andre produkter"></li>
   <li k="ProduktKategori" value="Tilhenger"></li>
   <li k="ProduktNavn" value="Basic 750"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did not work. I am trying to get the "value" attribute from the tag "li". Example i want to print out "Andre Produkter"

Comment: ul[k='redmeta'] li[value='Andre produkter'] {
  
} is it work for you?

Comment: Yes that will work, but this gives me the value of the text inside not the "value" attribute. and this "value" attribute is dynamic so it changes over pages. i want to print "andre produkter" not the text value inside

Comment: Also if you want to get the value not selector then there is no solution with CSS. You should try via JS.